# Как удалить строки из таблицы POSTGRE с подзапросом (DELETE ... SELECT)?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Ккак делается `DELETE .. SELECT` в *Postgre*?

Таблица - очень большой лог, без *ID* (не нужен):

```
CREATE TABLE log (
  username character varying(15),
  creation_date timestamp without time zone,
  ip_address character varying(20)
)
```

Вот запрос, который выделяет из лога старые записи, если их больше заданного кол-ва:

```
SELECT username, creation_date
from (
 select username, creation_date, row_number() over (
  PARTITION BY username order by username asc, creation_date desc
 ) rownum from log
) x where x.rownum > 2
```

Как их удалить-то?

Answer (score 3):

Оказывается просто. Нашел - [ctid](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/ddl-system-columns.html).

```
DELETE FROM log WHERE ctid IN (
  SELECT ctid from (select ctid, username, creation_date, row_number() over (PARTITION BY username order by username asc, creation_date desc) rownum from log) x where x.rownum > 2
)
```

Всем спасибо.